# Where is agent Murphy in season 3?

Tags: character, narcos

As far as I know there is no mention of agent Murphy in the third season.

I was wondering if this is how it was in reality that agent Murphy did not work against Cali Cartel or maybe the actor playing Murphy did not want to continue acting for Narcos?

Or was there some other reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because he went back to US after Escobar's death.

From [Wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Murphy_(civil_servant)) page of Stephen Murphy:

> He became a local police officer in West Virginia, where he stayed for four years, before being transferred to Bogotá, Colombia, where he played an important role in the killing of Escobar. After Escobar's death, in December 1993, he returned to the United States in 1994, where he continued to work with the DEA until his retirement in 2013. Today he heads a law-enforcement private consulting firm.

So show is just being true to the real story of Murphy.

Also official words from the actor himself:

> **Will Boyd Holbrook reprise his role as Steve Murphy for “Narcos” season 3?**
>
> **Holbrook:** “We’re still working it out. Steve didn't retire from the DEA until, I believe, two years ago. He was very active in the DEA
>   for a long time so I’ll leave that up to you to find out,” the actor
>   said.
>
> However, when Holbrook had been tapped to play a role in “Logan,” he
>   changed his statement and confirmed he is out from the “Narcos”
>   series. He said that the “Narcos” casts and staff are already shooting
>   some scenes while he is busy on his movie, confirming he is not
>   involved on the new season. - (Source: [telegraph.co.uk](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/on-demand/0/narcos-season-3-does-return-netflix-will-happen-wake-pablo-escobars/))

Comment: Pedro Pascal is a great lead for the show in season 3, and Peña is a good character, but I did miss Boyd's narration. Pascal's voice wasn't as good for the narration.